# How to instantiate Class class for a primitive type?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do this, but doesn't work:

```
public static Class loadIt(String name) throws Throwable {
  return Class.forName(name);
}
assert foo.loadIt("int") == int.class; // exception here
```

How should I do this properly?

Comment: Primitive ... say it with me, prim-uh-tiv ... without classes, but just some raw data ... :)

Comment: there is really no good reason why Class.forName() doens't work for primitive type names. Just return the damn `int.class` for "int".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't, because primitives are not objects.

What you are trying currently though is not yet instantiation - it is loading a class. But you can't do that for primitives. `int` is indeed the name that is used for `int` types, whenever their `Class` object is obtained (via reflection, for example `method.getReturnType()`), but you can't load it with `forName()`.

Reference: [Reflection tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html):

> If the fully-qualified name of a class is available, it is possible to get the corresponding Class using the static method Class.forName(). *This cannot be used for primitive types*

A solution to instantiate a primitive is to use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) `ClassUtils`, which can get the wrapper class corresponding to a given primitive:

```
if (clazz.isPrimitive() {
    clazz = ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(clazz);
}
clazz.newInstance();
```

Note that this assumes you have the `Class` representing the int type - either via reflection, or via the literal (`int.class`). But it is beyond me what would be the usecase of having a string representation of that. You can use `forName("java.lang.Integer")` instead.

Comment: As per your edit: I don't see how the commons-lang solution can be applied on an input which is of type `String`.

Comment: @Bozho the solution with `commons-lang` is not very relevant here, I suppose. I don't have `clazz`, but just a `name` (which is `String`).. BalusC proposed a workable solution

Comment: @yegor256, @BalusC - my solution was actually answering the question title ;)

Comment: @Bozho could you please show how `loadIt()` method looks like if commons-lang ClassUtils is used?

Comment: @yegor256 do you want to _instantiate_ a primitive, or get the corresponding `Class`?

Comment: @Bozho to get `Class`, as in my original implementation of `loadIt()` (see above).

Comment: @yegor256 BalusC's solution solves that, but tell me how are you obtaining the string in the first place? There is some bigger picture that we don't see here. What's the ultimate goal of this?

Comment: `clazz.newInstance()` on a wrapper type makes no sense; as the name suggests, these types wrap a value, therefore, they do not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 7):

We use or own simple method (Java 7+):

```
/**
 * Return the java {@link java.lang.Class} object with the specified class name.
 *
 * This is an "extended" {@link java.lang.Class#forName(java.lang.String) } operation.
 *
 * + It is able to return Class objects for primitive types
 * + Classes in name space `java.lang` do not need the fully qualified name
 * + It does not throw a checked Exception
 *
 * @param className The class name, never `null`
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if no class can be loaded
 */
public static Class<?> parseType(final String className) {
    switch (className) {
        case "boolean":
            return boolean.class;
        case "byte":
            return byte.class;
        case "short":
            return short.class;
        case "int":
            return int.class;
        case "long":
            return long.class;
        case "float":
            return float.class;
        case "double":
            return double.class;
        case "char":
            return char.class;
        case "void":
            return void.class;
        default:
            String fqn = className.contains(".") ? className : "java.lang.".concat(className);
            try {
                return Class.forName(fqn);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class not found: " + fqn);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: very good, just missed `String`s like _"boolean[]"_, _"byte[]"_, _"short[]"_, ...

Answer (score 4):

Try ApacheCommons ClassUtils like this:

```
ClassUtils.getClass(className)
```

Works for primitives nicely.

The full name for the class is org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the best you can hope for is to create a map of primitives to their Autoboxed equivalent and return a class of that type.