# Initializing an ArrayList whose type is specified by the user

Tags: java, command-line, constructor

I'd like to initialize an array whose type is specified by the user via command line. That is, if user enters "int", I'd like to do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Similarly, if user enters "String", I'd like to do:

```
ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now of course I can do this by bunch of if-else statements however, I wonder whether there's a clever way to do it. Assume the types user enters is always a primitive type, i.e. int, string, boolean etc.

Comment: What do you intend to do with `res`?  (In pseudocode.)

Comment: It's just a random name for the array. I'll fill with bunch of random elements.

Comment: I'm asking what you intend to do with the resulting arraylist.

Comment: I found 2 posts which may be of interest - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032898/how-to-instantiate-class-class-for-a-primitive-type.  They both discuss how to dynamically translate a primitive type to it's corresponding Class object.

Comment: There might be a neat way to do what you want to do, but it probably doesn't involve generics. It really is hard to say without having a more substantial description of what you want the program to do with the lists.

Comment: @Radiodef Well, I just wanted to abstract away the complexity. I'll read some text files into the arrays and do some filtering later. I don't see how this is related though.

Comment: @SpiderRico It's because of what Adam's answer says. Generics are compile-time only. When the program runs there is no particular difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>`. So any solution that's more general than hard-coding separate paths with different compile-time types (such as with if...else) won't involve generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual types of generic arrays, i.e. between the < and > only exist at compile time, aka [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)...

This means that only `ArrayList<Object>` only really exists at runtime... Therefore what you're asking doesn't really make sense.

There isn't enough information in your question so far to help you further...

Comment: If there isn't enough information in the question to give a proper answer, shouldn't this be a comment instead?