# How to get the initialisation value for a Java Class reference

Tags: java, reflection, initialization, default-value

I have a `Class<?>` reference for an arbitrary type. How to get that type's initialisation value? Is there some library method for this or do I have to roll my own, such as:

```
Class<?> klass = ...
Object init = 
    (klass == boolean.class)
  ? false
  : (klass == byte.class)
  ? (byte) 0
  ...
  : (Object) null;
```

The use case is I have an arbitrary `java.lang.reflect.Method` reference, which I want to call using arbitrary parameters (for some testing), which may not be `null` in case the parameter is a primitive type, so I need to specify some value of that type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032898/how-to-instantiate-class-class-for-a-primitive-type

Comment: @YakovBurtsev: That isn't strictly related...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To do it without 3rd party libraries, you may create an array of length one and read out its first element (both operations via `java.lang.reflect.Array`):

```
Object o = Array.get(Array.newInstance(klass, 1), 0);
```

Starting with Java 9, you could also use

```
Object o = MethodHandles.zero(klass).invoke();
```

Comment: Nice thinking with the array trick. That `MethodHandles.zero(Class)` method is very cool and will do for me.

Comment: @LukasEder when method handles are an option, you can bind the `zero` handle directly to the parameter, avoiding any conversion/boxing overhead, e.g. `MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(method); while(handle.type().parameterCount() != 0) handle = MethodHandles.collectArguments(handle, 0, MethodHandles.zero(handle.type().parameterType(0))); 
 /* prepared ... */ 
 handle.invoke(); // invokes the method with all-default values`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Defaults`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Defaults.html#defaultValue(java.lang.Class)) class from guava library:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Defaults.defaultValue(boolean.class));
    System.out.println(Defaults.defaultValue(int.class));
    System.out.println(Defaults.defaultValue(String.class));
}
```

Prints:

```
false
0
null
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness' sake, this is something that I think belongs to a reflection API, so I have added it to [jOOR](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR) through [#68](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR/issues/68)

```
Object init = Reflect.initValue(klass);
```

Notably, [Guava has a similar tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988581/521799) and there are [JDK utilities that can do this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989209/521799)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a parameter of a Method is primitive, call `isPrimitive();` ont the parameter type:

```
Method m = ...;
// to test the first parameter only:
m.getParameterTypes()[0].isPrimitive();
```

Comment: I don't need to check if the type is primitive. I want the initialisation value regardless of the specific primitive type.