# Compare an Object to a primitive type

Tags: java, reflection, types, primitive

I'd like to perform a safety check for my `getClass().getField(...).set(...)` where the value I am setting should match the type of that field, (int x = 1 should only allow Integers to be set). The problem is, I'm having a hard time finding ways to compare the two. Currently this is the code:

```
int foo = 14;

Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField("foo");
Object source = this;

// make the field accessible...

public void safeSet(Object newValue) throws IllegalAccessException {
    // compare the field.getType() to the newValue type
    field.set(source, newValue);
}
```

I've tried a lot of things, and searched around the web for quite a bit, but cannot find an answer which solely focuses on this usage of it. I've tried things like `field.getType().getClass().equals(newValue.getClass())`, `field.getType().equals(newValue)`, and more, and they do not work. How can I reasonably compare a primitive field.getType() to an Object value passed in, or, how would I, in this case, compare an `int`, to an `Integer`?

Comment: The association of the primitive types to their wrapper classes is indeed missing in java. One remark: either `getClass().getField("...")` or `Xxx.class.getDeclaredField("...")` to deal with child classes.

Comment: `if(field.getType().isPrimitive() && field.get(source).getClass() != newValue.getClass()) /* error */`. Works since primitive values can never be `null`, hence, there’s always an old value whose wrapped representation must have the same type as the wrapped new value. When you don’t want to read the field, check out [how to get the default value for a type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989209/2711488)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 :
Check `field.isPrimitive()`. If it returns true then it's a primitive type. and proceed to step 3.

Step 2: 
If it's not primitive then you can directly check
`field.getType() == newValue.getClass()` and then set the value

Step 3: 
if it's primitive then you need to have a static map

```
public final static Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
static {
    map.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
    map.put(byte.class, Byte.class);
    map.put(short.class, Short.class);
    map.put(char.class, Character.class);
    map.put(int.class, Integer.class);
    map.put(long.class, Long.class);
    map.put(float.class, Float.class);
    map.put(double.class, Double.class);
}

Class<?> clazz = map.get(field.getType());
then check clazz == newValue.getClass() and then set the variable.
```

Comment: Fine solution but for non-primitive types inheritance means to check for `field.getType().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())`.

Comment: In Step 2, `==` does not work if the assigned value is a subtype of the original, or the declared type is an interface. Use [Class.isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) instead, it is a general solution.

Comment: @gaborsch I agree with you when you need subclasses to be included. For Strict class checking e.g. here he wants only primitive data types to be changed.  ==  will work.

Comment: I wish this wasn't the solution I had to go with, but sadly, I can't find another generic way that works. Perhaps in the future Java can implement something which helps with this?

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is [Class.isAssignableFrom()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-)

Because you want to assign a value to a field, this is the built-in solution to do that.

```
if (getClass().getDeclaredField("foo").getType().isAssignableFrom(newValue.getClass())) {
    ....
}
```

It works for primitive types, too.

Comment: Attempting this with my values results in an assert of false for the check. Same values, Object is '2', assert fails